# Is it haram to keep a dog if you keep it outside the house?

Tags: fiqh, dogs, pets

Assalamualaikum,

I'm just curious, is it allowed to keep a dog if I keep it outside and don't allow it to enter the house? Or is it still prohibited to keep a dog even though you keep it outside?

Thank you in advance, have a great day :)

Comment: Walaikum assalam,have a great day you too.https://youtu.be/177_2Y-qxnc

Comment: @Obaid thanks! I will check that out

Comment: How are you supposed to have hunting dogs, if you can't?

Answer (score 1):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. So first we need to realize if dogs are allowed or not. We see from the following hadith:

> Ibn ‘Umar said the Prophet ordered dogs to be killed, except hunting dogs or sheepdogs or dogs used for looking after animals. (Bukhari and Muslim.)

Now lets say you wanted to keep a dog that was not allowed to keep?

> That the Messenger of ALLAAH (ﷺ) said: "Whoever acquires a dog - with the exception of a dog to guard livestock, a hunting dog, or a farm dog - each day a Qirat is deducted from his reward." (Grade: Hasan)

However, at the end we find that if one were to keep a dog it must be kept outside. Why?

> Abu Huraira said ALLAAH messenger told that Gabriel came to him and said, "I came to you last night and was prevented from entering simply by the fact that there were images at the door, for there was a figured curtain with images on it and there was **a dog in the house**. So order that the head of the image which is at the door of the house be cut off so that it may become like the form of a tree; order that the curtain be cut up and made into two cushions spread out on which people may tread; and **order that the dog be put out.**” ALLAAH Messenger then did so.
> Tirmidhi and Abu Dawud transmitted it.

> The Prophet [SAW] said: "The angels do not enter a house in which there is a dog or an image." (Nasai)

Overall only specific dogs should be kept. If they are not allowable types (farming, hunting, etc.) then you will lose a lot of reward daily. And then it has to be **understood that they be kept outside no matter what type of dog** is being kept. And please make sure you treat them nicely (nice housing, good food, good drink).

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.

Answer (score 0):

In the first what is the purpose of getting a dog? (it may be necessary)

I know it is fun to get a Dog, but also not everything is fun is good in Islam.

I think being on the safe side is the best way!, better not to pet a Dog either inside or outside, (I also think it is a bit hard to make him instantly outside).

How about getting a Cat, Bird, Fish instead? how beautiful are they!

I hope you understand, Thank you!

Comment: Yeah I know I like cats more actually but there's this one kind of dog that I like I mean I could argue that other than as a pet it can also be a guard dog (since it's a Great Dane and it's a giant breed) but I don't wanna use a loophole like that.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't say it is haram to have a dog
Only a few rule you gotta follow if you wanna have one
1 must be outside
2 don't let him/her lick any dishes that you use
3 after petting/playing with them go wash yourself if you just pet them through the door just clean your hands.
That's pretty much all there is to it
I have a dog so I understand the responsibility of having one and personally
I love seeing how people who don't like dogs react when they see him through the door
Always a fun way to crack some jokes